# 12th International Mathematica Symposium

Tags: discussion

I hope that users of this StackExchange do not mind posting an announcement about the upcoming [International *Mathematica* Symposium (IMS)](http://www.ims2015.net/Welcome.html), to be held in Prague from January 12-14, 2015. The IMS is an interdisciplinary conference for and by all users of *Mathematica* in the physical and life sciences, mathematics, engineering, graphics and design, arts and music, education, industry, finance, and commerce.

If you use *Mathematica* in research or teaching, or if you have developed or are developing products based on Mathematica, then IMS is an opportunity to share your results with like-minded colleagues. IMS (also on Facebook [here](https://www.facebook.com/ims2015)) has built up a deserved reputation as an exceptionally convivial and friendly gathering.

September 30 is the closing date for [abstract submission](http://www.ims2015.net/Submission.html), so hope to meet many of you at IMS 2015 in Prague early in the New Year.

Comment: Voted to move to meta. But perhaps it's better to post an add.

Comment: It's an important ad, but I agree meta is the right venue (though I wish the rules were a bit more indulgent in this regard).

Comment: @DanielLichtblau Meta + featured tag (added by a mod) gives it way more exposure than a post on main. Once the cache is updated, you should be able to see it on every single page on the site (see the yellow box in the sidebar).

Comment: @rm-erf Ah. I did not know that. Thanks.